# How to insert unicode string in PowerBuilder when using datastore/datawindow?

Tags: unicode, powerbuilder

The SQL Insert statement below is used to insert unicode string and it is working successfully when executed in SQL Server Management Studio or Query Analyzer.

```
 Column Specs:
 SONUM    VARCHAR(50)
 CONTRACTNUM NVARCHAR(150)
 FNAME     VARCHAR(70)

 INSERT INTO SCH_EDI_3B12RHDR ( SONUM, CONTRACTNUM, FNAME ) 
 VALUES ( 'DPH11309160073CC' , N'Globe MUX Project(客户合同号:NA)' , 'TEST' )
```

Is it possible to implement the prefix  N when using a datastore/datawindow for insert operation? If yes, how? Below is the current script in PB which successfully insert the data but the chinese character/s was replaced by '?'(question mark).

```
ls_sonum = String(dw_1.Object.shipmentOrderNum[1]) //This holds the value : DPH11309160073CC
ls_chinesechar = String(dw_1.Object.contractnum[1])   // This holds the value : Globe MUX Project(客户合同号:NA)

dw_1.SetItem(1,'sonum',ls_sonum)
dw_1.SetItem(1,'contractnum',ls_chinesechar)
dw_1.SetItem(1,'fname','TEST')

dw.AcceptText( )

IF dw.Update( )  = 1 THEN 
   Commit Using SQLCA ;
END IF
```

Comment: What version of PB? v10 and later should be working natively in Unicode, so there's nothing to do, I'd expect, as long as the receiving column in the database was of the correct data type. Also, what PB database driver? I don't think MSS was ever brought to Unicode.

Comment: @Terry, it's version is 10.2 and DBMS driver is OLE DB.

Comment: Do you have DisableBind=0 in your connection string? It's known (http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C4333e6c6@forums-1-dub%3E) to allow Unicode, but can have side effects. Too bad you weren't up to PB11, so that you'd have the option of the SNC driver.

Comment: @Terry, appreciate the info that you've provided. As of now, there is no DisableBind=0 in the connection parameter but i can explore on this. Is there any documentation regarding the side effects or possible implication if DisableBind=0 if being implemented?

Comment: Given that the side effects are just hearsay, my suspicion is that there's no documentation other than the link, and any other discussions that might show up in a search. The link is to Sybase's old newsgroup archive; it's a good place to search.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook yourself on the sqlpreview event of dw/ds and add the N' yourself. Or if you use static (or disable?) bind you don't need to do anything at all.
It's all explained in the online docs.

Answer (score 0):

I verified that the OLE DB driver for PB version 10 supports Unicode. You can find the information in [this Sybase document on page nine](http://www.sybase.com/content/1036154/L02684_PB_InternationalizedApps_WP.pdf).

**ODBC/ JDBC /OLEDB/ ADO.NET DATABASE SUPPORT**

Client/Server PowerBuilder 10 applications can exchange Unicode and ANSI data with databases
supported by the ODBC, JDBC, OleDB, and ADO.NET database interfaces without requiring
special settings.

Suggestion would be to try forcing a different encoding when using the string function, there are four choices (see code example below)

The **encoding parameter** is one of the following:

■ EncodingANSI!

■ Encoding UTF8!

■ EncodingUTF16LE! – UTF-16 Little Endian encoding (PowerBuilder 10 default)

■ EncodingUTF16BE! – UTF-16 Big Endian encoding

```
// use the correct encoding for your actual data
ls_sonum = String(dw_1.Object.shipmentOrderNum[1], EncodingUTF16BE! ) //holds DPH11309160073CC
ls_chinesechar = String(dw_1.Object.contractnum[1], EncodingANSI!) // holds Globe MUX Project(客户合同号:NA)
```

It is possible that I'm leading you down the wrong path but I think this would be worth trying out and may solve the problem.